# Opening text file with xdg-open

Tags: files

I am (very) new to the terminal and Ubuntu.  I want to open a text file for practice, and have been trying to use xdg-open with no luck. I have tried:

```
xdg-open /home/myusername/Documents/test.odt
open /home/myusername/Documents/test.odt
open test.odt      %(From within the folder)%
```

[image: terminal screen capture]

Comment: What is the error code you get? xdg-open exits with error 1 through 4 when there is a problem. And what you posted is the actual command?

Comment: 'xdg' undefined near line 1 column 1                   yes, those were the actual commands I tried

Comment: I just tried "xdg -open /file/path"   still no luck

Comment: can you do the same as I did in the answer? and show us the actual error? Upload the image, add the URL to the question and someone (if not me) will change the url into an actual image.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, trying to see how to get screenshot from the terminal

Comment: I have the screen shot.  How do i post it?

Comment: (1) you appear to be trying to open a document from within `octave`: octave only understands octave commands - you need to exit from octave and run the command in a regular Linux shell **or** run it via the octave `system` command e.g. `system('xdg-open somedoc.odt')` (2) the command is `xdg-open` **not** `xdg -open`

Comment: @steeldriver: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: @Fabby apologies... done

Answer (score 2):

Based on your screen capture, you appear to be trying to open a document from within `octave`. You are also mis-typing the command: it is `xdg-open` not `xdg -open` (which will be interpreted as a command `xdg` followed by an option or options `-open`).

The `xdg-open` command is usually run from a regular Linux shell rather than from inside octave. If that was your intention, then you can exit octave by typing

```
exit
```

at the `octave>` prompt, or by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

If you really intended to open a document from *within* octave then you will need to execute it as a valid octave command by wrapping it in a `system()` call e.g.

```
system('xdg-open somedoc.odt')
```

Comment: And upvoted! **:-)**

Answer (score 0):

Example on using xdg-open with a newly made file:

[image]